Issues running XLookup from VBA UserForm. Cant get it to work no matter what I try (even other peoples code)
Ive always wanted to get into coding and never really had enough time to put aside to do so until recently, thanks to my job. I had been put in charge of a project to create a database of materials that I deal with at work and once I seen the benefit of using VBA in my spreadsheets and tables I started soaking up as much as I could, and in my opinion I've come a long way. So far I've figured everything out myself by reading and experimentation, but I knew that would only get me so far.
Im currently stumped on running XLookup from a UserForm. Ive been developing my module code in sections (kind of like sandboxing) and then throwing it in with everything else once I have it figured out.
Problem: When i execute the macro it returns nothing at all (well, it spits out a zero because i threw a 0 at the end for "if not found"), no matter how I structure it. Somethings telling me its because of data types but ive messed with declaring different data types and nothing works.
My "SandBox" worksheet is "Sheet1", and the table on that sheet is "Table1" with 3 columns ("Name", "Address", "Phone")
My userform has a combobox "NameBoxCMB", and 2 Textboxes ("AddressBox", "PhoneBox"). The comboBox has been populated with a list from the "Name" column, and I'm trying to return the returnArray's to their corresponding textboxes. Fairly simple, until its not. And I've used XLookup a lot before in just regular excel formula.
Ive tried declaring every worksheet and table before the actual line of code itself, ive tried not declaring, I've also messed with different data types (setting formatting on the worksheet columns to the same declared data type in the module) and nothing....
Private Sub SearchButton_Click()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

Me.AddressBox.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.XLookup(Me.NameBoxCMB.Value, tbl.Range(1), tbl.Range(2), 0)
End Sub


Ive messed with the .Range values too (.Range(1), .Range("1"), .Range("Name"), .Range([Name]), .Range([[Name]])
Any help would be great, thank you.

Try Dim rg As Range: Set rg = tbl.DataBodyRange: With Application: Me.AddressBox.Value = .XLookup(Me.NameBoxCMB.Value, rg.Columns(1), rg.Columns(2), 0): End With. If you don't have MS365, use
With Application: Me.AddressBox.Value = .IfNa(.Index(rg.Columns(2), .Match(Me.NameBoxCMB.Value, rg.Columns(1), 0)), 0): End With.

Thanks for the comment, I gave it a try but its saying wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment.

Might be helpful to share the code that populates NameBoxCMB from the listobject data.

If none of the suggestions are working for you, then the issue is likely related to your data.

Try:
Me.AddressBox.Value = Application.XLookup(Me.NameBoxCMB.Value, tbl.ListColumns(1).Range, tbl.ListColumns(2).Range, "", 0)
or
Me.AddressBox.Value = Application.XLookup(Me.NameBoxCMB.Value, tbl.ListColumns("Name").Range, tbl.ListColumns("Address").Range, "", 0)
or
Me.AddressBox.Value = Application.XLookup(Me.NameBoxCMB.Value, tbl.Range.Columns(1), tbl.Range.Columns(2), "", 0)
Microsoft documentation:

ListObject.ListColumns property (Excel)


Sub demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("Table1")

    Dim sName As String: sName = "bb"
    Debug.Print Application.XLookup(sName, tbl.ListColumns(1).Range, tbl.ListColumns(2).Range, "", 0)
    Debug.Print Application.XLookup(sName, tbl.ListColumns("Name").Range, tbl.ListColumns("Address").Range, "", 0)
    Debug.Print Application.XLookup(sName, tbl.Range.Columns(1), tbl.Range.Columns(2), "", 0)
End Sub

Output in Immediate Window:
 22 
 22 
 22 

Table1:


Yeah Ive tried all ideas up there and its still not working. And Ive tried it on 2 different computers

@FrankSutton Is there any error? What does not working mean? I've uploaded a screenshot and testing script.

I wouldn't use XLOOKUP at all.  Use FIND instead.
Public Sub Test()

    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
    
    Dim FoundRange As Range
    Dim ReturnRow As Long
    Dim ReturnValue As String
    
    With tbl.ListColumns("Name").DataBodyRange
        Set FoundRange = .Find(What:="Darren", _
                               After:=.Cells(1, 1), _
                               LookIn:=xlValues, _
                               LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                               MatchCase:=False)
                               
        If Not FoundRange Is Nothing Then
            ReturnRow = FoundRange.Row - tbl.HeaderRowRange.Row
            ReturnValue = tbl.ListColumns("Address").DataBodyRange.Cells(ReturnRow)
        Else
            ReturnValue = "Item not found."
        End If
    End With

End Sub

